# Best practice for inserting values to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting into MySQLi and I am slowly getting the hang of things. I have a piece of code that works for inserting a form values into a DB.

I don't want it to just work though, I really want to do best practice. I believe I have everything covered, though would appreciate at extra set of eyes to help look at something I might of missed, or a better way at constructing the code.

```
// Check the form is posted
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {

// Let's get things started
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, active, username, masteradmin, properties) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Form variables
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']); 
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']); 
$active = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['active']); 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']); 
$masteradmin = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['masteradmin']); 
$properties = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['properties']); 

// Bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $name, $email, $password, $active, $username, $masteradmin, $properties);

// Execute and Go!
$stmt->execute();

// Get the ID of what has been inserted
$helloid = $db->insert_id;

// Wrap things up
$stmt->close();

// Send it on its merry way.
$insertGoTo = "index.php";
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));

}
```

Comment: some would say PDO is best practice

Comment: Mods, this should be on CodeReview. @Brandrally, you don't need to use both `mysqli_real_escape_string` and prepared statements.  The latter is sufficient (and superior)

Comment: Don't escape, use only parameterized queries. Hash your passwords. Plain text passwords are very bad practice.

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review, if **a)** the code works **and b)** the code isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: Hi @Quill, thank you for the feedback. I had no idea that there was a code review. Appreciate it.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Appreciate the thoughts. I didn't know CodeReview existed. Definitely would have posted it there had I have known.

Comment: @chris85 Cheers, yeps definitely will hash up the password for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick pieces of feedback

1. You don't need to use both `mysqli_real_escape_string` and prepared statements. The latter is sufficient (and superior).
2. Never store cleartext passwords!!  Always hash and salt before storing.

To store, first do:

```
$hashed_pwd = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

//now you can store $hashed_pwd in DB
```

At login, to verify the user's submitted password:

```
//first select user from DB with matching username

//then verify the cleartext pwd submitted
if(password_verify($cleartext_pwd, $hashed_pwd)){
    //correct password
}else {/*wrong password*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for inserting values to *MySQL* database is to use **PDO**.

```
// Define the data array to insert
$insert = $_POST;

// remove the extra fields 
unset($POST['submit']);

// create a hash
$insert['password'] = password_hash($insert['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Define a query.
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, active, username, masteradmin, properties)
        VALUES (:name, :email, :password, :active, :username, :masteradmin, :properties)";

// Prepare, execute and Go!
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)->execute($insert);
```